# How to constantly check if a network drive exist?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, animation, scroll

I am running a check constantly in my application to check if a network drive exist/available every few seconds. If the drive does not exist, I want to scroll text label inside a panel at the top of my application saying that the drive is unavailable or is disconnected. How can I check if drive doesn't exist and show the whole text before rechecking again? Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Dim DrivePath As String = "C:\"
    If Not Directory.Exists(DrivePath) Then
        LabelText.AutoSize = True
        LabelText.Text = "Drive unavailable or disconnected."
        LabelText.Parent = PanelInfor
        LabelText.Location = New Point(PanelInfor.ClientSize.Width,
                                    PanelInfor.ClientSize.Height / 2 - (LabelText.Height / 2))
        Timer3.Start()

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    If LabelText.Right < 0 Then
        LabelText.Left = PanelInfor.ClientSize.Width
    Else
        LabelText.Left -= 10
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific with what issues you are facing?

Comment: my timer2 checks every 1 second. In that every 1 second, if my network drive does not exist shows a text label inside a panel and starts timer3 that way it scroll from right to left. My problem is that on my timer2, it doesn't allow my scroll to run through the top before rechecking again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are resetting the position of the label to start every time you hit Timer2_Tick.

This should fix your issue

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

    Dim DrivePath As String = "C:\"
    If Not Directory.Exists(DrivePath) Then
        LabelText.AutoSize = True
        LabelText.Text = "Drive unavailable or disconnected."
        LabelText.Parent = PanelInfor
        If (Not Timer3.Enabled) Then
            LabelText.Visible = True
            LabelText.Location = New Point(PanelInfor.ClientSize.Width,
                                    PanelInfor.ClientSize.Height / 2 - (LabelText.Height / 2))
            Timer3.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf Timer3.Enabled Then
        Timer3.Stop()
        LabelText.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
```